# How to initialise a pointer to an array of integers in a single line of code?

Tags: c

Initializing a pointer to integer is done using the following code:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int * p= a;
```

My Question is why a one-liner below doesn't work and if there is another way.

```
int *p = &{1,2,3};
```

Note: This question is **not** about the best performing or best readable version of the code. This is just to know why a very similar code doesn't work.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Just use the two lines of code. It works!

Comment: C99 has compound literals.

Comment: Why do you want a separate pointer variable? What is the problem you want to solve with it? Since arrays naturally decays to pointers (to their first element), can't you simply use it when a pointer is needed?

Comment: Yup. It works. I just asked out of curiosity.

Comment: Curiosity killed the cat (other 80 pop groups are available)

Comment: *Why* do you need to do it in one line?  Saving lines of code is only useful to textbook publishers. Making code *less* understandable is only good for [the International Obfuscated C Code Contest.](http://www.ioccc.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason why you can't do this in 2 lines of code like you already do. It is clear and readable.

If you *must* complicate things for the sake of it, you can write a *compound literal*:

```
int* p = (int[]){1,2,3};
```

This will yield exactly the same machine code as the code you already have, so no version is better than the other.

Comment: _so no version is better than the other._ - I disagree - the more readable version is better

Comment: @EdHeal Personally, I find them both equally readable. This is very trivial code.

Comment: Didn't know about them before: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Compound-Literals.html. Thanks man.